SYSTEM account of domain controller does not have permissions to change password of domain user
Have some software that runs as the SYSTEM account on the domain controller of an Active Directory. Part of what the software does is change passwords of select accounts at pre-determined intervals and report the change back to another server associated with the application.
The software runs at customer sites. For 99+% of customers, the software works out of the box.However, for some customers, when changing the password, it fails and the logs report an access error. HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)
All Windows Server VMs I create on AWS and run the software on work out of the box.
To be clear, on the domain controller, the service is running as the SYSTEM account--NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM or say for computer BoxX, sometimes seen as BoxX$.
If I look on an example server that works, that account is a member of:
CN=Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access
CN=Builtin,DC=evotestmsp,DC=local
CN=Cert Publishers,CN=Users,DC=evotestmsp,DC=local

And the PrimaryGroup is: CN=Domain Controllers,CN=Users,DC=evotestmsp,DC=local
There are no special groups that the DC SYSTEM account belongs to that indicates that it would be able to change passwords...it just is able. Maybe Domain Controllers group allows it...IDK, but I assume any DC would be a member of this group. The tech support guys haven't gotten this information to us when it has failed.
Even if I try a command like: Get-ADGroupMember 'domain admins' -Recursive | select name, I don't see anything to do with the SYSTEM account or BoxX$. I only see domain users' names.
Would there be any flag that would prohibit changing the password by the SYSTEM account if the account was disabled... or needed to change password on next login?
It seems like I'm looking for a needle in a haystack permission or setting that I can't find.
Thanks in advance.

Which version of Windows Server? Maybe group policies in place or security baselines who prevent it. It could be a security threat also

"Everyone" (by default) has the permission to CHANGE a password on ANY/EVERY account  Changing a password requires knowledge of the current password.
To confirm Is this process RESETTING the account?  That is a different operation.  Not trying to split hairs, but these are two different operations.

You should look at the ACL of some test account that you are trying to reset the password of. Right click the user object, select properties, go to the security tab (advanced features needs to be enabled in ADUC in order to see that tab) and see what permissions the system account has and compare it to what it has on domains where it works.

@Guido It is Server 2022. You say it could be a security threat? How could I check that?

@semicolon It doesn't require knowledge of the prior password to change the password of an account through an API. For instance, PowerShell command Set-ADAccountPassword requires no such knowledge. The service I am using uses the C# UserPrincipal class and uses the SetPassword method of that class.

Set-AdAccountPassword requires the '-Reset' parameter when not supplying the old password or the credential of the account being changed.  "SetPassword" is specifically not the "ChangePassword" method of that class.  I just needed to know how you were doing it, so I could point you to the correct permission.

By Default SYSTEM is granted Full Control of all objects in the directory.

You would need to look at an account on which a password reset operation fails and review its ACL.  From there you should be able to see where the "Deny: Reset Password" permission is applied, where it is set and from where its being inherited.  If the account in question is a highly priviledged account, it is also possible/probable that the ACL of the object is managed/secured by the SDProp process (the ACL of the AdminSDHolder object is essentially cloned onto it hourly).  In that event, the ACL of AdminSDHolder would need to be adjusted to include the Allow: Reset Password permission for SYSTEM.
Or, the application/process could be rewritten to use the ChangePassword method, but that would require knowledge of the current password.

Here is a primer on the SDProp process and AdminSDHolder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory#protected-groups

Just had a meeting with a client who was having the problem. Software was installed not on DC but secondary or tertiary DC. Used psexec -sid powershell.exe to create SYSTEM PowerShell. Ran Set-ADACcountPasword with -newpassword and -reset arguments. Failed with Access Denied. Went into AD and added the machine to domain administrators and the software that sets the password started working. With a previous client today, support had them install on primary DC and it did not work. They did not try adding machine as Domain Admin.

That's a whole lot more information - and completely different.  SYSTEM on a domain controller accessing another resource "over the network" isn't SYSTEM on a domain controller.  It is the computer object.  Try adding an -Server localhost to the powershell.
Anyway, without seeing the ACL on the object in question, it'll be hard to determine where the problem is.
